# Are locals destroyed before or after evaluation of a function return value?

Tags: c++, return, destructor, object-lifetime

I am thinking of making a class which represents *ownership* of a synchronization primitive, something like this:

```
class CCriticalSectionLock
{
public:
    CCriticalSectionLock( CCriticalSection &cs ) : cs( cs )
    { cs.Enter(); }
    ~CCriticalSectionLock()
    { cs.Leave(); }
private:
    CCriticalSection &cs;
};
```

This looks like a good way to be able to take ownership during a function and ensure  ownership is released even if there are multiple exit points or exceptions.  It does, however, raise some subtle issues about exactly when the compiler will have various things evaluated.  Consider the following use:

```
int MyMethod( void )
{
    not_locked(); // do something not under lock

    CCriticalSectionLock myLock( someCriticalSection );

    locked(); // do something under lock

    return ...; // some expression
}
```

AFAIK, C++ lifetime rules would guarantee that `not_locked()` would be called *before* the lock is taken, and that `locked()` would be called while the lock is held.

However, what I am not so clear on is exactly when the expression being returned would be evaluated *with respect to the point at which the lock destructor is called*.  Is it guaranteed that the expression will be evaluated *before* the destructor?  I would think so but I'm not 100% sure, and if not it could lead to very subtle, intermittent, hard-to-find bugs!

Comment: Duplicate: [What comes first - stack unwinding or copying of return values](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8923018/220636)

Comment: @nabulke So that's why I didn't find anything... I was looking for destruction/evaluation but that was hiding under unwinding/copying.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If they weren't, that would be very problematic.

Indeed, consider the following code :

```
int function(){

    MyClass myObject;
    //stuff
    return 5 + myObject.getNumericalValue();
}
```

with `getNumericalValue()` a simple member function that returns an int based on computations on member variable. If the expression was evaluated after the destruction of `myObject`, you would have undefined behavior, and using locals would be impossible in return statement (which isn't the case).

In your case, the lock will be destroyed *after* the evaluation of the return statement.

To add some strictness to that, let me quote the standard (§3.7.3/3, emphasis mine) :

> If a variable with automatic storage duration has initialization or a destructor with side effects, **it shall not
>   be destroyed before the end of its block**, nor shall it be eliminated as an optimization even if it appears to
>   be unused

The end of the block, for a function, is *after* the return statement.

Comment: Good point on being able to use a local in the return;  I had considered that too but wondered if any optimization might be able to reorder it in the event the return didn't reference the local.